# What is 'fighting' in 'He went down fighting'?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What part of speech would the word **fighting** be in:

> He went down **fighting**.

Comment: A verb, of course. What else could it be?

Comment: A participle, to be precise.

Comment: Think about what it means. He is fighting as he goes down. Fighting isn't the object of the verb.

Comment: The word "fighting" is a verb heading a clause functioning as an adjunct in clause structure. It's a depictive adjunct giving descriptive information about the referent of the subject "he".

Comment: It is an idiom: to go down fighting/to go down singing, etc.

Comment: @BillJ In my language, when translated, this would be what we call a 'verbial adverb' (adverb constructed from a verb). Is there any possibility that this would be an adverb in English? Given that it basically tells you of a 'manner' in which he went down.

Comment: @MichaelMunta No: it can only belong to the word class (part of speech) verb. Functionally, though, it could be called adverbial, a term often used instead of adjunct. It doesn't qualify as a manner adjunct, which are almost always _ly_ adverbs and occasionally preposition phrases, but not clauses.

Comment: @BillJ ok. Can you please elaborate on the 'verb heading a clause'? What does that mean?

Comment: "Fighting" is a verb functioning as the 'head' (main word) of the clause.

Comment: @BillJ so you are saying there are two clauses here. 'He went down' and 'fighting'?

Comment: There are two clauses. The matrix clause is "He went down fighting", which  has "went" as its verb. Within that clause is the embedded subordinate clause "fighting". Note that for every verb there is a clause, and that some subordinate clauses can consist of just a verb.

Comment: Incidentally, the expression "to go down fighting" is an idiom meaning "to offer resistance until ultimately defeated", so analysing it grammatically is pretty pointless. Whatever, you have an answer to your original question: "fighting" is a verb.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of "He did A while B." Except the "while" has been elided. You could be more confident if you added the missing word or words.

- "He went down *while* fighting."
- "He went down *while continuing to* fight."

So yes, as one of the comments says, a participle. It is a verb (here with "ing" added) that is used as an adjective. Here it modifies "he." He was fighting when he went down.

(Note that I modified this due to a comment. I previously said that it modified "went down." That was incorrect.)

Comment: Words aren't "used" as adjectives. Adjective is a word class (part of speech"; it is typically used as a modifier, which is the case here. It's depictive, not temporal.

Comment: So words are not scare quoted as adjectives but they are used as modifiers. Right-ee-oh. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/participle

Comment: The word "fighting" is a verb heading a clause functioning as an adjunct in clause structure. It's a depictive adjunct giving descriptive information about the referent of the subject "he". Btw, dictionaries are fine for meanings, but hopeless for grammar!

Comment: @BillOnne don't you mean an adverb instead of an adjective? Check my last comment on the question.

Comment: @MichaelMunta Text of my answer modified due to your comment.

Comment: To me, 'He went down while fighting' has a very different meaning to 'He went down fighting'. The former describes a (doubtless resultative) punctive event within a durative exploit, while the latter (far more idiomatic) describes the manner (not quitting) of the unfortunate's demise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The two things you describe are equivalent.  Pretending you didn't use a thesaurus to write your comment does not change that.

Comment: You can see that 'go down fighting' is classed as an idiom by eg [Farlex Dictionary of  Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+down+fighting) whereas I doubt you'll find that 'go down while fighting' is, Bill. // I attribute when (as here) I quote.